# Trademark on name "Galactica"

Tags: trademark

I am not very knowledgeable in the matters of international trademark law so I was hoping to get some insight here. I am considering a development of a computer game and the best name I came up with is **Galactica**. However, I am unsure whether I can use this as the name **Battlestar Galactica** is obviously a trademarked name.

The game shall fall into the genre of so called *grand strategy* games which are essentially large empire simulators with a single game playing out for many hours and deep game mechanics. The game would be situated in galactic environment, the player would explore star systems colonize planets and make diplomatic connections and wage wars with other species in the galaxy.

Could I get into trouble for naming such a game **Galactica**?

Comment: A good resource is the WIPO global brand database (https://www3.wipo.int/branddb/en/). I see >100 total registrations for "galactica", but not all might be relevant (expired, uninteresting countries, different area). Trademarks are specific to some kind of goods or services, so that a fashion trademark would not prevent your entertainment use.

Comment: ok, this is very helpful. So it seems that the relevant category is 42 (how fitting :) ), which includes computer software. However, the fact that someone has a trademark registered in this category does not necessarily mean that I cannot use it, right? The trademark should be more narrowly focused. For example there is a Data Science service named Galactica, which is registered under 42, they provide data science software, however, it in no way collides with the game I want to make so I should have no problem using the name on a game, is that correct?

Comment: I think this is the point where you are asking for legal advice. We can't provide that.

Answer (score -5):

You have to look up whether Galactica is trademarked, not Battlestar Galactica or anything else.

If it is not trademarked you are good to go.